# How to send files via lan between two computers

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-xp, lan, file-transfer

Does anyone know a software which allows you to send files between two computers connected directly via lan cable (machines run WinXp and Win7)? I've already tried to use shared files and folders feature but machines doesn't recognise each other. Both machines have the same workgroup and unique names. Shared internet connection does work however.

Comment: Do you want to send or copy files? Have you tried using the xcopy or copy command in the CLI? e.g. copy 'file' '\\ipaddress\path\'?

Comment: @Tog still doesn't work. it says: path not found

Comment: Have you tried simple file sharing? For Win7: http://www.home-network-help.com/file-sharing-in-windows-7.html For WinXP just enable it in the folder options (view tab). Be warned, simple file sharing is insecure so it's not suitable for use on a public network.

Comment: @Tog as i already said: yes i have. but with no good((

Comment: What IPs/subnet do the machines have?

Comment: @xstnc winxp (server) ip: 192.168.0.1, mask: 255.255.255.0, win7 (client) is configured to get everything automatically. only this configuration works fine.

Comment: So you shared a folder on winxp? Can you ping the Winxp machine from the win7 (`ping -4 192.168.0.1`)? And what is the ip and mask of the Win7 machine (`ipconfig`)?

Comment: @Rik well i have exectuted both commands on win7 machine.. `ping -4 192.168.0.1`: timeout, 100% data loss. `ipconfig`: ip: 192.168.0.14, mask: 255.255.255.0, gateway: 192.168.0.1 (gateway on win7 is the same as ip on winxp, as far as i know it's a good sign, right?)

Comment: @user2543574 Well. The gateway should be ok if you're running the DHCP-server on Winxp (via ICS). But the fact you can't ping 192.168.0.1 is not good. could you *temporarily* disable the firewall in Winxp to see if it helps. Maybe the file-sharing in it is check off (by accident). After disabling the firewall you should be able to do the `ping -4 192.168.0.1` on the Win7 machine (without timeout). Just for clarification how are the PC's connected? I take it you have 2 network adapters in the Winxp machine of which one is connected to the internet and the other to the Win7?

Comment: @Rik WHOA!! it did ping)) i disabled firewall (eset smart security 6, windows firewall was already disabled) and now i have no timeout. yes, i have winxp with two lan ports and win7 with one.

Comment: @user2543574 Can you do a `\\192.168.0.1` in the run-dialog and see the Winxp shares? If you do then you need to look for an option in eset smart security to enable file sharing (or disable all the checking on the second network adapter).

Comment: @Rik file sharing works fine now! thank you guys! but what with firewall?

Comment: @user2543574 You can look [here](http://kb.eset.com/esetkb/index?page=content&id=SOLN2141) for the settings in eset smart security to allow file-sharing etc. I'll add a note to Kirk's answer so you can accept his.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the machine where you shared the folder, open the command prompt or type `CMD` in run (to open RUN in Windows use <kbd>Key</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>). Then type `ipconfig` (followed by <kbd>enter</kbd>) so you will get the IP-Address of that machine. Now go to another PC and open the run again and type `\\` followed by the found IP-Address and press <kbd>enter</kbd>.

For instance:

`\\192.168.15.1` and press <kbd>enter</kbd>

Remember to replace `192.168.15.1` with the IP-Address you found on the main-machine.

**Edit:**

You do need to enable the firewall to let traffic for file-sharing through.
For ESET Smart Security you can look [here](http://kb.eset.com/esetkb/index?page=content&id=SOLN2141) for the settings to allow file-sharing etc.

Comment: Would you know how to do it with command prompt? Something like "copy \\192.168.1.218\c:\myfile.txt". Is such thing possible?

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez a colon is not allowed in a UNC path.  You'd replace a colon with $ .  C$ only works though if you know an admin account on the remote computer.

Answer (score 0):

If both your PCs are in the same workgroup and connected, then Windows file sharing should work. However, computers may not recognize each other instantly (I remember direct connection caused such problems when I used it). You can try to force the connection:

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> on Computer 1 (the one that's *not* sharing a folder)
2. Type `\\Computer2` (or whatever the name of second one is, prefixed with double backslash)
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

It may take some time, but eventually Explorer window should show up.

Comment: thanks. but nope. it says: network path not found.

Comment: Have you double checked computer names and workgroups? Try restarting both PCs.

Comment: yes i did (more than twice)) both machines have WORKGROUP workgroup and unique names. some told me that widows firewall can be naughty sometimes. could it be that windows firewall doesn't let me do my business?

Comment: I don't think so, Windows Firewall is configured to allow file sharing out of the box. Which computer is the one sharing internet connection?

Comment: of course. sorry. winxp is sharing internet connection (is being a server for win7) while win7 is unable to give internet connection to winxp. i don't know why. winxp simply doesn't open any site on the web.

Comment: I've been setting up ICS from Vista to XP once and had the same problem. I'm not sure what fixed it, but once ICS was working file sharing started to work too. Are you using static IP on the client? If not, then it's worth giving it a try. Switching back to DHCP may work later.

Comment: well i don't really know what dhcp is (maybe something dynamic))).. i use winxp server with static ip and mask while win7 client is configured to get everything automatically. any other configuration won't work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12001/discussion-between-gronostaj-and-user2543574)